# Disable Git Credential manager for Windows from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using following

- Visual Studio 2019 Professional.
- Git for Windows 2.29.2

Suddenly I am getting following popup

[image]

I have tried to disable using command git config and also manually removed credential.manager from config and this popup still comes.

Due to this if I provided Azure DevOps credential, it get fails with authentication failed.

I have recently update the git and also tried to reinstall git extension for visual studio but it is not helping.

In popup if I provide username as PersonalAccessToken and password as PAT I have generated then everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

> In popup if I provide username as PersonalAccessToken and password as PAT I have generated then everything seems to be working.

That would be the recommended course of action: it should cache again your credentials and not ask for them again after that.

Recent [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) releases have switches to [Git Credential Manager Core  "GCM Core"](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core)

Make sure that, in command-line, `git config --global credential.helper` is set to `manager-core`.

---

Note that before Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), multiple "`credential-store`" backends can race to lock the same file, causing everybody else but one to fail---reattempt locking with some timeout to reduce the rate of the failure.

See [commit df7f915](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df7f915fb6fb28ea5a1e3103251c251e53a80b1b) (25 Nov 2020) by [Simão Afonso (`simaoafonso-pwt`)](https://github.com/simaoafonso-pwt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3d8f81f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d8f81f21bdce9e0472ae8921fab31e650030ecd), 30 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`crendential-store`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df7f915fb6fb28ea5a1e3103251c251e53a80b1b): use timeout when locking file
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Simão Afonso</sup>

> When holding the lock for rewriting the credential file, use a timeout to avoid race conditions when the credentials file needs to be updated in parallel.
>
> An example would be doing `fetch --all` on a repository with several remotes that need credentials, using parallel fetching.
>
> The timeout can be configured using "credentialStore.lockTimeoutMS", defaulting to 1 second.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/df7f915fb6fb28ea5a1e3103251c251e53a80b1b/Documentation/config/credential.txt#L31-L36):

> ### `credentialStore.lockTimeoutMS`
>
> The length of time, in milliseconds, for `git-credential-store` to retry
> when trying to lock the credentials file.
>
> - Value 0 means not to retry at all;
> - -1 means to try indefinitely.
>   Default is 1000 (i.e., retry for 1s).